# How to disable click events on a partial view until another particular partial view is rendered fully on the layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

There are multiple partial views on my main view. On **Partial View1**, there are some clickable icons. When ever these icons are clicked, the javascript event gets triggered and this event uses the data in the **Partial View2**.

**Issue:**
If i am clicking an icon before the **Partial View2** is rendered on to the screen, the InProgress popup wouldn't disappear. I need to refresh the screen all the time.

Could anyone suggest me how to disable the click events on **Partial View1**, until **Partial View2** gets rendered on to the screen.

Comment: How are you loading Partial View 1 and 2 ?

Comment: I'm not certain why the pop-up won't disappear, but you might consider using a flag (either a global JS variable that is initialized to 'false' until the dependent Partial View is loaded, or if needed on the icon level, a custom attribute that can be toggled conditionally).  Perhaps, you could check the status of the related View's loading progress in a more general way and exit the function called prematurely if it is not done. These approaches assume that you have full control over the related client side JavaScript code and know when the loading of the Views are completed.

Comment: @Shyju using @Html.Raw(Url.Action